# AWS S3 Usage Report

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am observing high data transfer out charges on mysite. While analyzing the S3 usage reports I found the below things which I don't able to understand

AmazonS3    GetObject   APS1-DataTransfer-Out-Bytes resource 2/1/2016 0:00  2/2/2016 0:00   80110323326

AmazonS3    StandardStorage APS1-TimedStorage-ByteHrs   resource 2/1/2016 0:00  2/2/2016 0:00   2.8585E+12

Check in the snapshot
[image]

What are these requests? Why their usage value is high? How can I prevent this?

I have gone through other answers and aws forms but could not find the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Basically they are how they describe themselves.

TimedStorage-ByteHrs is billed based on the gigabytes stored for the month. You are using the Standard storage class. You can use reduced redundancy storage or the infrequent access storage classes if your use-case permits either. If it is long-term backup files you can migrate those to Glacier for inexpensive storage. Refer to the different [Storage Classes](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/) for details on each.

DataTransfer-Out-Bytes is billed based on the number of gigabytes transferred out of your S3 account to the internet. The only way to lower the cost on this one is to not let your files be downloaded.

Comment: Can you explain not to let your files be downloaded? I have media streaming site.. And we do Facebook shares also. I have enabled public read permission only which becomes public open or download